# Adding contents to custom blocks

Tags: drupal-7, block, nodes, regions

I have created a custom region `regions['my_region']` from `mytheme.info`. I have added a block `myblock` to the region. Now how can I add contents to this block? Currently I have created a template file `region--my_region.tpl.php` and added contents there. Is this the right way? How can a normal user will be able to edit these contents?

Answer (score 0):

Generally in order for your users to add content to a block they would need the "Administer Block" permission. With this permission they can access the *admin>structure>block* page and then edit your block to change the content. You should do this with caution, as the "Administer Block" permission may give your users a lot of control over your site.

A better way to allow your users to add content to your new region might be to create a view on *admin>structure>views* with an attached "block" display. This view could be configured to show any type of content that your users can create.

Once you create the view, go to *admin>structure>block* and drag the block display into the new region you created.

Answer (score 0):

To display blocks content of custom region need to create file block--my-region.tpl with this content

```
<?php print $content ?>
```

in templates/block

And clear cache